# how to specify reference frames for H264 encoding in iOS?

Tags: ios, encoding, h.264, avassetwriter, encoder

I'm trying to improve the video quality of my video recording app, the resulted video always have 1 reference frames (see below), while we do see videos from other apps having this value of 2, I checked apple documents and searched SO, but not able to find any solution to specify this parameter, can anybody shed some lights here? many thanks!

```
Video
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
**Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame**
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=30
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 14s 868ms
Bit rate                                 : 1 527 Kbps
Width                                    : 540 pixels
Height                                   : 960 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 0.562
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 25.221 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 3.750 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
```

Answer (score 0):

Encoding.com supports the modification of reference frames via the  tag in their api. Here is their recommendation for this parameter:

"An important h.264 feature that allows for reference frames other than the one before or after the current frame. Using this parameter you can specify up to 16 reference frames. For live action 4-6 reference frames will suffice, but for animation 16 should be used. Generally the default is 6."

http://www.encoding.com/http-live-streaming-hls/#Encodingcom_HLS_Pro